# How to use signed integer division in assembly

Tags: assembly, masm, division, signed, irvine32

so for my project I have to prompt the user for a bunch of negative numbers, and find the average of those numbers, rounding to the nearest integer (for example -20.5 would be -20).
My question is how do I use the div instruction to do this? Whenever I run this code it works fine until it gets to the division part.

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

.data   
;variable definitions
average         SDWORD  ?
user_number     SDWORD  ?
counter         DWORD   0
sum             SDWORD  0

.code
main PROC

startloop:
call    readint
cmp     eax, 0
jge     end_loop
mov     user_number, eax
inc     counter
mov     eax, user_number
add     sum, eax
jmp     startloop

endloop:

mov     eax, sum
cwd
mov     ebx, counter
div     ebx
mov     average, eax

main ENDP

END main
```

By the way I'm using masm with irvine32 library. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: remainder goes to edx, also edx is used for upper 32 bits of 64-bit divident. can you try zeroing edx(with a backup of push-pop)

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean by that. I'm still pretty new to assembly.

Comment: edx and eax divided by ebx, result goes to eax, remainder goes to edx so you should make edx zero before division

Comment: It gives me an error though. What are you saying I change?

Comment: you are using eax and ebx so you should backup them with push eax, push ebx then in the end, you should reload them with pop ebx, pop eax so other programs using them are not corrupt

Comment: The `cwd` after `mov eax,sum` is wrong, the `cwd` does sign-extend `ax` into `dx:ax` (ignoring upper 16 bits of your `eax`),  so it would work for `div bx`. For 32b sum you may want to use `cdq` (sign-extends `eax` into `edx:eax` 64b value), and `idiv ebx` (signed divide of 64b `edx:eax` by 32b `ebx`, `eax` is 32b result, `edx` is remainder).